# issues about using "sudo rosdep init"

Tags: ros, archlinux

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I am new to ROS and I just installed ROS indigo on  ArchLinux using the tool "yaourt". When I finished installing all packages from AUR, I entered the command

**sudo rosdep init**

to initialize ROS. But an error came, saying

**Error: cannot download default sources list from: hrttps://raw.github.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/source.list.d/20-default.list**

I thought it was net connection problem, so I changed many networks. It seemed that none of the networks could reach that site... So I found a downloaded file **20-default.list** and was going to copy it to the corresponding directory manually, but I don't know where I should put the file. I found some solutions for Ubuntu and they said the corresponding directory for **20-default.list** is */etc/ros/rosdep/source.list.d/*, but when I checked my */etc*, I didn't even find the */etc/ros* !

Now I'm totally confused and hope someone can help me. Thanks a lot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257494/issues-about-using-%22sudo-rosdep-init%22/) by [jamszhao](https://answers.ros.org/users/29766/jamszhao/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-03-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That directory is likely created by the debian package on most other systems. You may need to manually create it on Arch.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2018-06-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0